# Easiest way to select distinct with least number of null

Tags: sql

I want to create a view over a table that has 500k rows and 10 columns. In that table there are duplicate id but with different amount of information, because some of the columns are NULL. My objective is to keep one column in case of duplicates, but want to keep the one with less number of NULL values.

Let me explain it with a quick example. I am working with a query similar to this.

```html
CREATE TABLE test (ID INT, b char(1), c char (1), d char(1))

INSERT INTO test(ID,b,c,d) VALUES 
(1,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(1,'B', NULL,NULL),
(1,'B','C',NULL),
(1,'B','C','D'),
(2,'E','F',NULL),
(2,'E',NULL,NULL),
(3,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(3,'G',NULL,NULL)

SELECT DISTINCT ID,b,c,d FROM test

DROP TABLE test
```

The result is

```html
ID  b     c     d
--------------------
1   NULL  NULL  NULL
1   B     NULL  NULL
1   B     C     NULL
1   B     C     D
2   E     F     NULL
2   E     NULL  NULL
3   NULL  NULL  NULL
3   G     NULL  NULL
```

However, the output I want to see is

```html
ID  b     c     d
--------------------
1   B     C     D
2   E     F     NULL
3   G     NULL  NULL
```

So, based on the id and if there are duplicates, I want to have the row with the least number of nulls. How is it possible?

Thank you very much

Comment: Add a few more rows of sample data, with different numbers and characters - and adjust the expected result. (To make the problem clearer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the row with the least number of `NULL`s, then you would basically count them:

```
select t.*
from test t
order by ( (case when b is null then 1 else 0 end) +
           (case when c is null then 1 else 0 end) +
           (case when d is null then 1 else 0 end)
         ) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

However, if you want one row per id with a non-NULL value in each column (if available) then @maSTAShuFu's answer is appropriate.

EDIT:

If you want one row per client, then simply use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by client_id
                                order by ( (case when b is null then 1 else 0 end) +
                                           (case when c is null then 1 else 0 end) +
                                           (case when d is null then 1 else 0 end)
                                         ) desc
                                ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for our answer. That was a simplified version of my problem. Actually I have a table with 500k clients with 6 columns and want to create a view that replicates that functionality: I want to keep one row per client and that row must be the one with least number of NULL values

Answer (score 0):

using MAX.

```
SELECT
  MAX(ID) ID,
  MAX(B) B,
  MAX(C) C,
  MAX(D) D
FROM test
```